# Nesting arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey guys am new to javasript app development..I have learned about objects and arrays and i got that values in the arrays can be called by index but in objects it cant be possible.

So i have tried the code

```
name = ['dfsdf','sfdsf']
var b = [[name,'DFDSF']];
console.log(b[0].name);
```

It gives me `undefined` Instead of returning the array name.

I just want to know how can i access like `b[index].nestedarrayname`.

It would be really helpful if you provide some example codes ..Thanks

Comment: `b` will look like `[[['dfsdf','sfdsf'], 'DFDSF']]`. Values don't contain information about variable *names*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I undrestant , you want to cal **name** , which is an array itself , so :

```
 name = ['dfsdf','sfdsf']
 var b = [[name,'DFDSF']];
```

you can do :

```
 1 - console.log(b[0][0]); // this will output an array which contains ['dfsdf','sfdsf']
```

**OR**

you must change your structure to this :

```
 name = ['dfsdf','sfdsf']
 var b = [
           {"name": name} // the right one name, is your actual name array , so this is b[0]
           ,
          'DSDSF' // this is b[1]
         ];
```

now you can call:

```
   console.log(b[0].name);
```

NOTE  :

in javascript  , you can call an element iside an array by its index , and you can call a property inside an object in two ways :

1 - Using .(dot)  like :   object.property

2 - Using ['']    like :   object['property']

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be an "associative" array, you would need to make the array element an object:

```
var b = [{name:'DFDSF'}];
console.log(b[0].name);
```

Comment: that was helpful ..gonna accept this in minutes ..;)

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to access a property via the `.` operator, JavaScript expects the object (an *array* in this case) to have an actual property with that name. Arrays have integer indexes in JavaScript, so to access it as-is you'll want:

```
console.log(b[0][0]);
```

However, if you *do* want an associative array, you can create the sub-indexes as objects instead (think JSON formatting):

```
var b = [{'name': name}, 'DFDSF'];
console.log(b[0].name); // b[0] is the object {'name': name}
                        // b[1] is the string 'DFDSF'
```